# Removing Email Attachments on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to create an iPhone app that will automatically remove specific attachments from email on the iPhone without user intervention…is this possible?
Thanks in advance, Lawson

Comment: What do you mean "remove"? Delete from the original email? Import into your program?